# How to chain cy.get in cypress

Tags: javascript, java, css-selectors, cypress, ui-automation

I'm trying to **get to #1 element then get to #2 element to click on #3 element**.

but I'm having a trouble with getting the correct CSS selector in Cypress.

[image]

How to write a test script for this?

I've tried
`cy.get('.ui.active.visible.button.floating.dropdown.fr-dropdown').contains('Delete yield').click()` but doesn't work.

Is there a way to get #1 first, then #2 to reach #3?
this is not a real code but something like this.

```
cy.get('.yield-event__date-and-text--container').contains('10kg')
cy.get('.ui.active.visible.button.floating.dropdown.fr-dropdown').click()
cy.get('.item.fr-dropdown__option').contains('Delete yield').click()
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write something like this using [find()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/find.html#Syntax):

```
cy.get('.yield-event__date-and-text--container').contains('10kg')
cy.get('.yield-event__date-and-text--container').find('i[class*="fr-dropdown__icon"]').click({force: true})
cy.get('.yield-event__date-and-text--container').find('Delete yield').click({force: true})
```

Answer (score 5):

As @RosenMihaylov says, you might find it easier to use the Cypress "relationship" commands which follow the HTML structure, rather than CSS selectors.

Also I think you would need two clicks - one to open the menu and the second to invoke the delete action.

Step 1 - looks like the text `devEnv_admin` identifies the card you want

```
cy.contains('div', 'devEnv_admin')
```

which gives you the 7th div down.

Step 2 - the dropdown you need to click is 2nd sibling to the above

```
.siblings('div.note-event__dropdown')  // list of siblings matching the selector
.eq(0)                                 // take the first (and only)
```

which gives you the parent of the dropdown button.

Step 3 - but it looks like the child of that which has class `button` might have the click event handler (you might have to experiment here because elements with event handlers are sometimes difficult to find)

```
.children('div.button')   // list of children matching the selector
.eq(0)                    // take the first (and only)
.click();
```

which should open the menu, but it might take some milliseconds to appear

Step 4 - wait for the div with the text you need

```
cy.contains('span', 'Delete yield')   // this form of .contains() waits for the text
  .click();
```

In summary,

```
cy.contains('div', 'devEnv_admin')
  .siblings('div.note-event__dropdown')  // list of siblings matching the selector
  .eq(0)                                 // take the first (and only)
  .children('div.button')                // list of children matching the selector
  .eq(0)                                 // take the first (and only)
  .click();

cy.contains('span', 'Delete yield')   // this form of .contains() waits for the text
  .click();
```

There are other paths through the DOM elements and other selectors you can use, like `.next()` and `.parent()`.

A lot depends on where the event handlers are attached, which is easiest to find out by looking at the source code.

---

Alternatively, using `within()`

```
cy.contains('.yield-event__date-and-text--container', 'devEnv_admin')  // pick the card
  .within(() => {  // restricts commands below to this card
    cy.get('div.button.dropdown').click();
    cy.contains('span', 'Delete yield').click();
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a detailed explanation how to implement my suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanations, it really helped me a lot :)

Comment: @Ackroydd thanks a lot, using within() works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

Cypress docs show 3 ways [Children](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/children.html#Syntax) or [Find](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/find.html#Syntax) or [Within](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/within.html#Syntax).

Personally I use .within, when I want to work in the scope of the element and .find - when I want to be able to work both within the scope and outside.