# Changing with another command in Cypress

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress, ui-automation

I'm trying to click one after another within the same card but I'm having **issues with changing commands** in Cypress

[image]

The code below doesn't work but I'm just showing what I have right now

```
 cy.get(Card_Type_1).contains(devEnv_admin).find(#1).then((Dots_3) => { 
      Dots_3.click()
    })
```

I'm very new to coding as you can see my code, thanks!

Comment: Can you post the expanded dom structure of the card type_1 row, containing all the elements ?

Comment: Re [How to chain cy.get in cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64763492/how-to-chain-cy-get-in-cypress), what is different from that question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [within()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/within.html#Syntax). It scopes all subsequent cy commands to within this element. Useful when working within a particular group of elements

```
cy.get(Card_Type_1).contains('devEnv_admin').within(() => {
  cy.get('i[class*="ellipsis"]').click()
  cy.contains('Edit yield').click()
})
```

Comment: thanks a lot, using within() works like a charm cy.contains(Card_Type_1, devEnv_admin')